# Parameters to Microsoft Report

Tags: vb.net, parameters, reportviewer

Why it wont show me parameters to reportviewer on form 2 with this code.

```
Imports Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms
Public Class Report
Private Sub Report_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    Dim parmlist As New List(Of ReportParameter)()
    parmlist.Add(New ReportParameter("CompanyName ", Form1.TextBox1.Text & "Report"))
    parmlist.Add(New ReportParameter("ClientName", Form1.TextBox2.Text))
    parmlist.Add(New ReportParameter("ClientAdress", Form1.TextBox3.Text))

    ReportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(parmlist)

    Me.ReportViewer1.RefreshReport()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Code doesn't showing problems. I also added parameters with same values and designed as on picture. [Image](http://pokit.org/get/?4d80faf03801749228319191c7151f8b.jpg)

Comment: What do you mean when you say that it won't show you parameters?

Comment: @JohnSaunders it show an empty report without any values.

Comment: When you run the report "manually", and you enter parameters, does it show you a report that is not blank?

Comment: How do you mean manually. On form 1 i enter all data in textboxes. When i click button it should to create me a report with those values in it. But this is what i get [Picture1](http://pokit.org/get/?df8dc200d5487c8cf5c0fb377f858535.jpg) [Picture2](http://pokit.org/get/?5ce1b8e04cc3827f23b90c87a21cf7ec.jpg)

Comment: I mean, using the "report viewer". Or when you run the report through the report designer.

Comment: Using report viewer with this code it works great .          `Dim ime As New ReportParameter("CompanyName", Form1.TextBox1.Text)
        Dim imec As New ReportParameter("ClientName", Form1.TextBox2.Text)
        Dim adresa As New ReportParameter("ClientAdress", Form1.TextBox3.Text)
        ReportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(ime)
        ReportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(imec)
        ReportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(adresa)
        Me.ReportViewer1.RefreshReport()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using this code it orks perfect.

```
 Dim ime As New ReportParameter("CompanyName", Form1.TextBox1.Text) 
    Dim imec As New ReportParameter("ClientName", Form1.TextBox2.Text) 
    Dim adresa As New ReportParameter("ClientAdress", Form1.TextBox3.Text)  
    ReportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(ime)     
    ReportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(imec) 
    ReportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(adresa) 
    Me.ReportViewer1.RefreshReport()
```